# Calculate number of days between two dates if condition in another column is met

Tags: excel, formula

I need help with creating a formula for a status sheet (I'm horrible with if statements).  I have three columns, Status, Start Date and Completed Date.  I need a formula that will calculate the days between start and completed dates if the status is equal to Completed or Cancelled.  If the status is not either of those it needs to calculate between start date and [today].  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, something like this:

```
=if(or(Status="Completed",Status="Cancelled"),CompletedDate,Today())-StartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
=IF(A2<>"",C2-B2,TODAY()-B2)
```

..or this, if the other cells are containing some other word that doesn't start with C

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C",LEFT(A2,1))),C2-B2,TODAY()-B2)
```

..also the third column could be renamed to "End Date" since cancelled isn't completed

..or this, if a start date is required to exist and to be smaller than the end date

```
=IF(B2>0,IF(AND(C2>B2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C",LEFT(A2,1)))),C2-B2,TODAY()-B2),0)
```

Comment: If you flip the statements around, `ISERROR(FIND(A2,"Completed|Cancelled"))` will be `FALSE` for "Cancelled" or "Completed", but `TRUE` for "Open", "Ongoing", etc...

Comment: I was just offering an alternative to using `SEARCH` to check if the first letter is "C" - for example, if "Call Client" is a Status option.  *'If the Value in cell A2 is not a Substring of "Completed|Cancelled", then...'*

Comment: @Chronocidal Nice! seems more secure, feel free to edit my answer